# npm install throws ENOENT

Tags: node.js, node-modules

I'm trying to use NPM to install some packages, but for some reason NPM throws an ENOENT error: [screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2XXJB.png). Can anyone tell me what's going on here?

Answer (score 1):

NPM is trying to invoke bash, which doesn't exist on windows. You should be able to fix this by installing [Git Bash](https://gitforwindows.org/)